# Como puedo meter una imagen de fondo en un Dialog en flutter?

Tags: flutter, dialog

tengo un inconveniente que no puedo resolver, quiero meter una imagen de fondo en un Dialog para ello en el hijo del dialog  tengo un container y este container quiero que si o si tenga borders redondeados pero que la imagen de fondo se adapte al borde redondeado ya intente haciendolo o una la imagen se desborda y me tapa el borde o queda mas chico que el container aqui agrego mi codigo en este caso la imagen queda mas chico en los laterales.

```
 void showDialogWhereIsPin(BuildContext contextoVerPin){
  final tamanoPhone = MediaQuery.of(contextoVerPin).size;
 showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return Dialog(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.circular(20.0)), //this right here
    child: Container(

      decoration: BoxDecoration(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
         color: Colors.white
      ),
      height: tamanoPhone.height * 0.5,
      child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))
                      ),
                      child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/imagenes/fondo_fridolin.jpg"), 
              height: tamanoPhone.height * 0.5, width: 300,)
                    )
            ],
      )
    ),
   );
  });

}
```

ahora tampoco quisiera que el dialog se vea el largo de toda la pantalla o si existe alguna propiedad o como hacer para achicar el alto de un dialog? tambien me vendria de gran ayuda, muchas gracias aqui dejo una imagen de como me queda de feo.

[image: Asi me queda mi dialog eso blanco a los laterales no me gustan]

o tambien si existiera algun paquete en ayudarme a hacer eso? aunq seria el ultimo recurso ya que no quiero usar paquetes.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo, puedes usar `AlertDialog` agregándole `Center` encima para que tenga constraints y así pueda mostrarse del tamaño que le indiques, mira este ejemplo que preparé:

```dart
void showDialogWhereIsPin(BuildContext contextoVerPin) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, //this right here
            content: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                child: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(
                      'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4759213.jpg',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Solo cambia el `Image.network` por `Image.asset("assets/imagenes/fondo_fridolin.jpg",fit: BoxFit.cover,)`

Tambien puedes cambiar el `height: 100`,  que le puse al container y usar tamaños que elijas o incluso puedes quitarle y que se ajuste al contenido que agregues.

Comment: Muchas Gracias diegoVeloper